# Chart of Accounts on google sheet with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, accounting

i'm trying to create "chart of accounts" for a small accounting project , to generate accounts numbers based on accounts names ,

i already tried sheet's formulas but it isn't ideal since i'm using a form to add new accounts and it will be unsorted ,

i want to convert all formulas into arrayformulas to make it dynamic but i couldn't manage to solve that without getting slower calculation time  ,
here is a:
[copy of my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MCT03QhanN13VZpCmCeujJ_rgL7xVM2xVmZxOW0KXjQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking for a better formula in 'Parent' and 'Account', right?

For 'Parent' i suggest SWITCH formula that is useful for many conditions. It also provides default value when no conditions are met.
I also use array_constrain formula that limits arrayformula to filled rows only (checks whether F column has some content).

[image]

Try in L2:

```
=array_constrain(
ArrayFormula(switch(K2:K,
2,F2:F&"|0|00|000|0000",
3,F2:F&"|"&G2:G&"|00|000|0000",
4,F2:F&"|"&G2:G&"|0"&H2:H&"|000|0000",
5,F2:F&"|"&G2:G&"|0"&H2:H&"|00"&I2:I&"|0000",
"0|0|00|000|0000")),
Count(F2:F),1)
```

'Account' column is easier as there are no conditions:
Try:

```
=array_constrain(
ArrayFormula(
TEXT(F2:F,"0")&"|"&TEXT(G2:G,"0")&"|"&TEXT(H2:H,"00")&"|"&TEXT(I2:I,"000")&"|"&TEXT(J2:J,"0000")
),Count(F2:F),1)
```

[image]

Here I also limit arrayformula to unempty rows using array_constrain.

Comment: thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it
, i managed to convert most of the columns into arrays
but still can't figure out column G,H,I 
, also my solution for column F,J didn't work properly 
since there are duplicates accounts under column A supposedly (Company A, Company B)
, i added your solution to my shared sheet so you can see what i mean